# Effective passing of large data to python 3 functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coming from a C++ programming background and am wondering if there is a pass by reference equivalent in python. The reason I am asking is that I am passing very large arrays into different functions and want to know how to do it in a way that does not waste time or memory by having copy the array to a new temporary variable each time I pass it. It would also be nice if, like in C++, changes I make to the array would persist outside of the function.

Thanks in advance,
Jared

Comment: Python != C++  ...

Answer (score 4):

Python handles function arguments in the same manner as most common languages: Java, JavaScript, C (pointers), C++ (pointers, references).

All objects are allocated on the heap.  Variables are always a reference/pointer to the object.  The value, which is the pointer, is copied.  The object remains on the heap and is not copied.